# prevent less linewrapp from breaking words -- split on white space only

Tags: less, pager

I want `less`'s linewrapping to be **smarter**... when `less`ing through text it's wrapping lines in such a way that words get broken up which makes reading difficult.  The smart way would mean only breaking lines on a   "space" character.

Is this possible?

In reading the man page and browsing the internet I surprised to see no other mention or inquiry of this.

If less can't do this is there another pager that can?

---

edits:

- Ideally this would effect could be toggled with a flag like `--cleanwrap`.
- Using this on stdin like `some-report.py | less -i --cleanwrap` is important.
- Ideally the pager will adjust to screen/terminal(tmux pane) resizing... maybe less isn't the right tool?  This could be sacrificed if the above features were possible :(

Comment: to my surprise: I started using vim with a custom vimrc for paging.  Does a better pager exist in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

`less` doesn’t have a built-in way of doing this, but if you use `lesspipe`, you can extend that to wrap files by extension.

The following, saved as `~/.lessfilter`, will word-wrap `.txt` files at 80 columns:

```sh
#! /bin/sh -

case "$1" in
    *.txt) fold -s -- "$1";;
    *)     exit 1;;
esac

exit 0
```

Make this executable, then make sure `less` is using `lesspipe`:

```
eval "$(lesspipe)"
```

and you should find that `less ...txt` will word-wrap.

This can be extended to handle other extensions, adjust the width to the terminal width, etc.

Comment: What about data piped to less?  I was hoping for a flag or switch like `--smartwrap`.

Comment: Is "wrap files by extension" the only possibility available in your suggestion?

Comment: No, you can filter data piped to less, but it’s harder to figure out what to do automatically...